# no MainActivity in the debug window in eclipse where I have the breakpoints

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging

I am trying to debug with eclipse but there is no "MainActivity" in the "debug" window , in order to select and check the variables where I have breakpoints.

I am debugging with the device attached.

I select debug as-> android application and then go to the debug perspective.

There, I select the name of the application and it gives me the "Threads" .

If I pause and select every thread , in no one I can find the MainActivity where I have set the breakpoints..

A screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Does the logcat show anything? Or the console "window", for that matter?

Comment: @DigCamara:Yes,the logcat shows a lot of information.

Comment: @DigCamara:I uploaded an image also.

Comment: That's right. Your MainActivity runs on the UI Thread ? What are you looking for?

Comment: @blackbelt:I am not familiar with waht you say (run on UI thread).I just can't see anything else in the 'Debug" window.Where can I find my MainActivity?

Comment: on the rigth panel, you have a list of breakpoints (under the breakpoints tab)

Comment: @blackbelt:It shows MainActivity [line: 121] - onClick(DialogInterface, int) 
and MainActivity [line: 122] - onClick(DialogInterface, int) 
and they are checked

Comment: you want the debugger to hit  the breakpoint?

Comment: @blackbelt:I want to see what  values have the variables where I have the breakpoints

Comment: If You have a breakpoint in your onClick, when you click on the button, if the delegate for the click in invoked the debugger will stop on the breackpoi t

Comment: @blackbelt:Yes!I have it on a dialog and I forgot to press the button.But now I can't find it.Is there a search engine?For example,I have my code in:

Comment: @blackbelt:setPositiveButton("Navigate",
       new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,

Comment: @blackbelt:I am going to variables tab -> dialog -> but there are a lot of things inside

Comment: @blackbelt:Ok , I found it.With F6 it goes there!Ok,thanks!Can you make it an answer in order to accept?

Comment: Actually I have not understand what your problem was

Comment: @blackbelt:Because I had the breakpoints inside an alertdialog and inside onclick,I never clicked in order to access the variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `debugger` to hit the brac`k`point, you have to perform the steps needed to reach it . In other word, since you have set a breckpoint inside the `onClickListener` of your dialog you have to click on the `Dialog`'s button in order to reach it.